# can someone explain why this works in IE browsers?

Tags: jquery, css

I had a cropping plugin that allowed for panning of an image when you dragged on it.  I wanted to apply a mask png over the top to give the impression of a cut shape.  [here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/6SmXx/)

It uses the css3 property `pointer-events:none;` on the image mask div, and it works in webkit browsers like chrome and firefox.  But it doesn't work in IE because `pointer-events: none;` only works on an SVG.

I did a lot of research in how to pass pointer events through divs.  I tried some solutions, but they were a headache, and some didn't work:

[so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

[forward mouse events through layers](http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/)

After looking more into the plugin I was using I was able to extend it and get it to work in an IE browser (tested 8 and 9 only) and other browsers, not utilizing the `pointer-events` option.  [Here is the jsfiddle of the new version](http://jsfiddle.net/thindery/E2ahY/).  **But I don't really know why it is working??** I basically did three things.

1. Pass the mask src in as an option
2. Add a check to see if a mask option is provided, if so load the function:

   ```
   if (this.options.mask_src) {
     var masksrc = this.options.mask_src;
     this.createMask(masksrc);
   }
   ```
3. Have the function append a div with mask image as the background image to the document div:

   ```
   createMask: function(m_src) {

       $('<div class="iviewer_image_mask" style="background: url('+ m_src +');"></div>').appendTo(this.container);
   },
   ```

Can anyone explain to me why this solution works for image panning that has a mask layer overtop?  It's like it is only applying mouse events to the image, and ignoring the mask layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be due to the location of the two `div` elements. In your non-functioning version, this is the html structure (simplified):

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="viewer2" class="viewer">
      <img />
    </div>
    <div class="image-mask"></div>
</div>
```

In your functioning version where you insert the element, this is what it ends up:

```
<div class="wrapper">   
    <div class="viewer iviewer_cursor" id="viewer2" >
      <img />
      <div class="iviewer_image_mask"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And by moving the mask into the `viewer` div in your original, I could get it to work [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SmXx/11/).**

I believe this makes a difference, since your script is binding to the `viewer2` div, so having the mask inside that apparently allows it to be functioning within the context of your script, whereas having it outside does not.